# UITableView scrollable background with UIColorWithImagePattern strange effect

Tags: uitableview, ios5, background, uicolor, ios6

I'm trying to set up in my UITableView a background which scrolls together with the table. One of the suggested approach (from previous research) is to use:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

Unfortunately this is the result on iOS 5.1:
[image]

The original background should be:

[image]

Apparently the problem doesn't affect iOS6. Any idea about how to fix it in iOS5?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your section header and footer views are messed up. Do you have following delegate methods setup correctly? iOS5 has an issues of putting them default if they are not setup. Not sure about iOS6 though.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section 

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section 

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: should I just place them with the forward call to the super class?

Comment: I mean something like
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [super tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
}

Comment: Do you know any alternative way to setup a background view which scrolls together with the table?

Comment: No..you have to implement them. For example you have to set title in titleForHeaderInSection and return it. If you don't want header then you have to return nil else it creates default header/footer. You can set the height if you want other wise default is 44 I think. I remember we had an issue with background view when uitableview height is more than 480! The view was coming empty after 480 but I was using backgroundImage property not background color. We then created background view image height with same as uitableview which worked fine. For your case seems you just need to set bkg color.

Comment: Also if you set tableview.background color to lightGray and implement these methods then background view will exactly look like you are expecting.